# A way to play Viber Push To Talk Files with Sentimental Value

Tags: audio, restore, viber-messenger

**I have a folder with a bunch of Viber (the communication app) Push To Talk audio files, in a PTT folder.**

They are from conversations between myself and my partner, who passed away a year ago. They were on a phone (**Moto G 2nd Gen**) that had a dead battery that I couldn't fix but somehow managed to resurrect itself last night after I charged it nonstop for 4 weeks. I was overjoyed and found my conversation with her in tact. However after browsing it a bit, as soon as I connected my old phone to the internet (I was planning to backup the conversation to my google drive), it seemed to overwrite my conversation with her, possibly as I have Viber installed on my newer phone (**Moto G 3rd Gen**) that I have been using for the last year. I now only get the 'Welcome to Viber' message when I open the app. Surely the entire conversation wasn't deleted in that split second? I see that viber has 404mb taking up the misc folder but I think that is mostly images (which I have saved)/ It could be in the cache but not sure how to access that.

So anyway, I find myself trying to salavage both the text messages and the audio files. I can't find the text messages so I fear they were immediately deleted when my phone synced. However I salvaged the PTT folder and I need to try and find a way to play these files outside of Viber, or convert them. Anything! There are over a thousand of these files of our voices. I need to hear her voice again.

I mailed Viber support but no luck there so far (though I'm still waiting for their latest reply).

It's so frustrating to have this surface after a year and then lose it again in the same evening.

**Any help appreciated (and that is an understatement) with how to play or convert these push to talk files or locate the text messages.**

Tony